# Постановка знаков препинания в БСП

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, бсп

*"Все они общались и шутили, но по их движениям, беглому взгляду было видно(:) каждый боялся за свою жизнь".*

Будет ли корректно поставить двоеточие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Все они общались и шутили, но по их движениям, беглому взгляду было видно —* [что] *каждый боялся за свою жизнь.*

Я бы поставила тире, потому что по смыслу не хватает союза "что". (Да и тире мне нравится больше — экспрессивно выглядит, солидно.)

Вот что пишет Розенталь.
2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении с изъяснительными отношениями встречается наряду с двоеточием также тире.
Сравните: *И судьи решили: если будет дождь, соревнования отменят; Заметил первый камень, решил — здесь клад, стал ковыряться* (Тендр.).

[§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)

*Сразу было видно: Збруев и Неелова — пара* (Д. Астрахан).
*Сразу было видно — такой молодец не пропадет* (Н. Бахрошин).